# PFUser query is not returning all fields for the PFUser object saved

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am having a problem where the objects (users) returned from a `PFUser` query do not contain all the class properties.

I did a bit of research, and found this question: [Parse iOS SDK, cannot get all fields from _User table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839055/parse-ios-sdk-cannot-get-all-fields-from-user-table)

The marked solution is to do a clean uninstall/reinstall of the app, but that doesn't work for me.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out what was happening was this..

In my User table, I created a few test users.

Then, I updated the User class to have an email field.

What was occurring was that any objects that are created before this new field is defined, will not return that property in a PFUser query, regardless of whether there's data in that field (for that object that was created BEFORE the field was defined)